# Count number of lines in a text file PS Im not allowed to use streamreader

Tags: vb.net

it always outputs the number 2 i dont know if the problem is from the code or from my program :

```
        DIM COUNT_LINE AS INTEGER =0
        If Not EOF(1) Then
            FileGet(1, True, RecordNumber:=1) 
            COUNT_LINE += 1
        End If
        last_record = COUNT_LINE+1
        TxtItemNumber.Text = last_record
        End If'''
```

Comment: When you say that you are not allowed to use a `StreamReader`, do you mean that your teacher is forcing you to use `FileGet` and the like? That form of file I/O is a holdover from VB6 and no one should be using it in VB.NET. If you're being taught that then there's not a lot you can do about it now but that is absolutely terrible. If you're paying for that course then I would suggest cutting your losses and looking elsewhere if you can. Be aware that, once you are finished, you'll have to unlearn some of the garbage they have taught you.

Comment: Also, the reason that you don't know why your code isn't working is that you haven't debugged it. You don't fix code issues just by looking at the result and reading the code. You set a breakpoint at the top and then step through the code line by line as it executes, examining the state at each step. You (should) know exactly what you expect to happen at each step so, if something else happens, you have found your issue. Even if you can't fix it, at least you can provide us with all the relevant information.

Comment: Yeah he is forcing us to do it that way else we will get bad grades and true theres alot of nonsense and garbage that we are being taught im trying my best to learn by myself , im not getting any help from my teacher

Comment: I think you'll find that that teacher probably learned some VB6 on their own and has learned almost nothing new since the advent of VB.NET nearly two decades ago. My commiserations.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.IO
```

The above is required for the following

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines("answers.txt")
    Dim count = lines.Count
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString)
End Sub
```

`.ReadLines` returns an IEnumerable(Of String) of the lines in the text file. The `.Count` of the enumerable will give you the count of how many lines are in the array. Can also be the one-liner given by @jmcilhinney in comments.

```
Dim count = File.ReadLines("answers.txt").Count
```

Comment: It would be better to use `ReadLines` and `Count`. If you actually need to use the data afterwards then `ReadAllLines` may be preferable but if you don't need the actual data then creating an array to store it all in is a waste of resources and time. Not that you'd actually notice in the vast majority of cases but you would in some and, as the more efficient code is no longer, it is definitely preferable.

Comment: I guess I am being dense but don't they both return a collection? An IEnumerable or an array.

Comment: `ReadLines` is an iterator, so it returns an object that can be enumerated but that object doesn't actually contain any data. Using `ReadLines` is equivalent to using a `StreamReader` to read one line at a time, increment a counter each time and then discard the line. That means that you are never storing more than one line at a time. `ReadAllLines` will retain every line, even if there are millions of them.

Comment: As a graphic example, I just wrote a text file with 100,000,000 lines using a `For` loop and it was just under 1 GB in size. I then used `File.ReadLines(filePath).Count()` and it took just under 4 seconds to execute. I then tried `File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length` and it threw an `OutOfMemoryException` after nearly 40 seconds. Obviously you're not going to be using text files of that size in most cases but it certainly illustrates the difference.